# How can we execute test cases using MTM

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-2012

I am using VS 2012, TFS and MTM. I have created test cases manually in MTM. When I try to run the test case it does not launch the  browser. Please let me know what needs to be done.

Comment: You need to provide more context before someone can give you an answer. Explain each step you have taken, when you received an unexpected result, and what you have tried to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

MTM does not launch the browser for you. I would recommend to get a clean test\recording that you:

1. Open the browser & Naviage to site
2. X number of steps to perform the test
3. Reset and Close the broswer

That way when you generate a CodedUI test from the recording you get something that can easily be automated.